# Pivoting a redshift table

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift

I think I am needing to pivot my database... or maybe there is some other function I can use to get the result I am looking for. Below is what my current dataset looks like (I actually have about 15 metrics):

```
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
|               ID                 | Metric 1|          Metric 2      | Overall Column |
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
| 1                                | Red     | Yellow                 |        Red     |
| 2                                | Yellow  | Yellow                 |       Yellow   |
| 3                                |  Yellow |                        |       Yellow   |
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
```

The overall column already has logic in SQL to say 'Red' if any of the Metrics are Red (even if they are Yellow, too), and then 'Yellow' if any are Yellow. There are also cases where Two metrics can be Yellow, Red, etc. What I am looking to do is add a new column that will show specifically which metric (or metrics) caused the overall value of Red or Yellow. What I am thinking is some sort of pivot that will, for each ID, have metrics as a row value and the corresponding color also as a row value (if that makes sense), and then I can do a listagg function and then join that table back on to my original dataset based on the ID.

Pivot example, ignore col2 & col3..

```
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
|               ID                 | col1    |          col2          | col3           |
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
| 1                                | Red     |                        |                |
| 1                                | Yellow  |                        |                |
| 3                                |  Yellow |                        |                |
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
```

After this I can listagg that table to capture multiple colors and then join it to the original table. The only thing I am leaving out there is if there is both Red and Yellow metric for an individual ID and then I do a listagg, that would bring both Red and Yellow even though the overall value is based on the Red metric. Hoping the SQL experts can help me out here.

Comment: If your starting point is the result of SQL, you may be better to show us the starting data and the starting SQL.  Then be explicitly clear about the final result you actually want.  I've been using Redshift for over 5 years, so I believe I can help, but your question is too vague and rambling, sorry.

Comment: @MatBailie The starting point is the first table I posted. It is created by a series of joins and case whens. Every 'Metric' column is just a logic field created using other fields. The final result I am wanting is the second table I posted. Table one has no duplicate IDs, with ~15 metrics. Table 2 has duplicate IDs since one ID can have a value for multiple metrics (hence the pivot)

Comment: Then, as I said, you should be showing the data from before the joins and case whens.  That's your starting data.  Pivoting is often possible at the same time.  Instead of creating the flat-file format, then pivoting, you just create the normalised format to begin with *(better performance, often simpler code, etc, etc)*.

Comment: For the desired results, you appear to be missing at least one column, the name/identifier of the metic that is red or yellow.  You also say that you then want to listagg() over it and join it back to the first table.  So that is ***NOT*** the final desired result.  Please show ***actual*** example inputs and ***actual*** desired outputs, not incomplete examples of interim steps.

Answer (score 1):

Redshift is currently based on Postgres 8.03 so it is missing a lot of functionality we've come to expect from Postgres over the last few years.  So trying to come up with a solution involving `unnest`, `array` or `lateral` is out of the question (I've learned this the hard way).

So barring the availability of all those new-fangled features, you can unpivot  the source table and create a set of each id and its metrics by using `union all` and creating a union for each metric column.

```
select a.id, metrics.metric
from tbl a
inner join (
    select id, metric1 metric from tbl where metric1 is not null
    union all select id, metric2 from tbl where metric2 is not null
    union all select id, metric15 from tbl where metric15 is not null
) metrics ON metrics.id = a.id
order by a.id, metrics.metric
```

**Results**

```
id | item
---+--------
1  | red
1  | yellow
2  | blue
2  | green
2  | pink
3  | orange
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/16e27/1/0)

Comment: Your colours are in the wrong order...  `Red and yellow and pink and green, purple and orange and blue, I can sing a rainbow, sing a rainbow, sing a rainbow too.`